# DataNucleus / NeoDatis - DB connection appears to close causing Persistable objects to be lost

Tags: java, database, database-connection, jdo, datanucleus

Using DataNucleus I have a problem seen in the **second INFO statement below** (2nd entry from the bottom).

When trying to read or edit an object after persisting it with `makePersistent()`, I get just null values, the INFO log indicates that the **object is no longer managed by the persistence manager** (though I'm performing these edits immediately after the `makePersistent()` call).

My guess is that the **connection** to my datastore (NeoDatis in local embedded/file mode) is being **closed**, thus the persistence manager stops managing it. But I'm just using the DataNucleus `org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory` class to create the connection.

Any idea why this might happen? Am I on the right track thinking that the closed connection messages are the problem?

*FQDN's shortened, and extraneous logs removed for brevity:*

```
DEBUG DataNucleus.Persistence  - Making object persistent : "a.b.c.User@22a866a9"
INFO  DataNucleus.Persistence  - Managing Persistence of Class : a.b.c.User [Table : (none), InheritanceStrategy : new-table]
DEBUG DataNucleus.Connection  - Connection added to the pool : [o.dn.s.neodatis.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl@28f337b, null] for key=o.dn.ExecutionContextImpl@59c12050 in factory=ConnectionFactory:tx[o.dn.s.neodatis.ConnectionFactoryImpl@3b626c6d]
DEBUG DataNucleus.Datastore  - Opening NeoDatis ODB for "neodatis:file:database/neodatis_primary_datastore.odb" : org.neodatis.odb.impl.main.LocalODB@13a183d2
DEBUG DataNucleus.Datastore.Persist  - Object "a.b.c.User@22a866a9" being inserted into NeoDatis with all reachable objects
DEBUG DataNucleus.Datastore.Persist  - Object "a.b.c.User@22a866a9" (id="15) persisted to NeoDatis
DEBUG DataNucleus.Datastore  - Committing NeoDatis ODB for "neodatis:file:database/neodatis_primary_datastore.odb" : org.neodatis.odb.impl.main.LocalODB@13a183d2
DEBUG DataNucleus.Connection  - Connection removed from the pool : [o.dn.s.neodatis.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl@28f337b, null] for key=o.dn.ExecutionContextImpl@59c12050 in factory=ConnectionFactory:tx[o.dn.s.neodatis.ConnectionFactoryImpl@3b626c6d]
DEBUG DataNucleus.Connection  - The connection has been closed : [o.dn.s.neodatis.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl@28f337b, null]
DEBUG DataNucleus.Reachability  - Performing check of objects for "persistence-by-reachability" (commit) ...
DEBUG DataNucleus.Cache  - Object "a.b.c.User@22a866a9" (id="15") added to Level 2 cache (loadedFlags="[YYYYYYY]", relationFields="null")
DEBUG DataNucleus.Transaction  - Committing [DataNucleus Transaction, ID=Xid=, enlisted resources=[]]
DEBUG DataNucleus.Lifecycle  - Object "a.b.c.User@22a866a9" (id="15") has a lifecycle change : "P_NEW"->"HOLLOW"
DEBUG DataNucleus.Transaction  - Object "a.b.c.User@22a866a9" (id="15") being evicted from transactional cache
DEBUG DataNucleus.Transaction  - Transaction committed in 7 ms
DEBUG DataNucleus.Lifecycle  - Object "a.b.c.User@22a866a9" (id="15") has a lifecycle change : "HOLLOW"->"P_NONTRANS"
DEBUG DataNucleus.Persistence  - Fetching object "a.b.c.User@22a866a9" (id=15) fields [authorities,createdFromIP,dateCreated,password,timeZoneID,username]
DEBUG DataNucleus.Datastore.Retrieve  - Object "a.b.c.User@22a866a9" (id="15") being retrieved from NeoDatis
DEBUG DataNucleus.Connection  - Connection added to the pool : [o.dn.s.neodatis.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl@39673d71, null] for key=o.dn.ExecutionContextImpl@59c12050 in factory=ConnectionFactory:tx[o.dn.s.neodatis.ConnectionFactoryImpl@3b626c6d]
DEBUG DataNucleus.Datastore  - Opening NeoDatis ODB for "neodatis:file:database/neodatis_primary_datastore.odb" : org.neodatis.odb.impl.main.LocalODB@621f6c18
DEBUG DataNucleus.Datastore  - Committing NeoDatis ODB for "neodatis:file:database/neodatis_primary_datastore.odb" : org.neodatis.odb.impl.main.LocalODB@621f6c18
DEBUG DataNucleus.Connection  - Connection removed from the pool : [o.dn.s.neodatis.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl@39673d71, null] for key=o.dn.ExecutionContextImpl@59c12050 in factory=ConnectionFactory:tx[o.dn.s.neodatis.ConnectionFactoryImpl@3b626c6d]
DEBUG DataNucleus.Connection  - The connection has been closed : [o.dn.s.neodatis.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl@39673d71, null]
INFO  DataNucleus.Persistence  - Request to populate fields of a.b.c.User@22a866a9 but this object is no longer managed by NeoDatis so replacing with a.b.c.User@7cf1cdfb
DEBUG DataNucleus.Datastore.Retrieve  - Execution Time = 5 ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I love learning new things, but why does it have to be such a painful process at times?
Ok right, this is an answer, not a question...

So, I did remove a key log line that would have helped others see the problem:

```
1795 [main] INFO DataNucleus.Transaction  - Non-tx updates are being committed to the datastore
```

The point is that the problems above were due to the fact that I was performing the actions outside of a transaction.

Actually that was only the first step, what was really happening was that I was performing the actions against a different `PersistenceManager` than the transaction was started on.

I had Spring managing transactions, but I was calling `jdoPersistenceManager.getPersistenceManager()`, which yielded a new `PersistenceManager` instance (A detailed debugging session uncovered this).

I should have been using spring to get the `PersistenceManager` that the spring transaction defined. Ultimately that meant extending `JdoDaoSupport` in my DAO object.

I feel smarter now, but somehow the learning never ends.

Comment: Can you clarify this a little further, or maybe post some code samples?

Comment: What platform are you using? I can tell you much about doing this outside of Spring and Data Nucleus, other than my problem was solved by properly opening and closing transactions. There are a lot of transaction managers out there which will start and stop transactions for you, or you might be doing it yourself (though I don't know anything about handling transactinos in DatanNucleus directly). But ultimately the problem was that I wasn't starting and stopping the transaction properly. This is all from memory as I went a wholly different direction after this anyway.

Comment: Thanks but never mind. I figured out that my problem was that when maven builds and tests, all goes well, but when eclipse builds (with the help of Maven supposedly) it does not always weave in the transactional code at compile time.